# Merging a tagged commit into a branch

Tags: git, bash, shell, version-control, terminal

I'm currently trying to merge a tag into a branch. The tag is not, I would consider, of an unusual format but Git persists on displaying Vim to enter a merge message even with one supplied in the command. Take the following for example:

```
git merge --no-ff -m "Released v1.1.0.1 to master." v1.1.0.1
```

I believe it has something to do with the tag format. I have tried merging branches and tags without full stops inside but the above ceases to complete without bypassing vim. I was just wondering if anybody had any advice on this issue?

Comment: Have a quick browse through [the Stackoverflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures), particularlly the linked section; your posts are already "signed" with your standard user card, rendering your signature unnecessary. :)

Comment: My apologies. Signature removed.

Comment: My git does not open editor when I do this. May be hack like `EDITOR=/bin/true git merge ...` will work (if useful message is pre-populated in the text editor)?

Comment: Yeah mine doesn't usually either. For merging of branches, it works fine but when trying to merge a tag, it appears. I got around the issue by creating a temporary branch for merging, cleaning up after myself once fully merged.

Comment: So the obvious workaround of just typing `Released v1.1.0.1 to master.` into the editor didn't work?

Comment: My idea was to automate the command so the editor would be bypassed. More actions occur after the merge hence the need to bypass it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this with this version:

```
david@davids-imac:~/t (master) $ git --version
git version 1.7.5.4
```

on Mac OS X 10.7 and, unless I misunderstood your question, it worked just fine. Maybe you are on a different OS/bash that is interpreting the '.' differently? My bash version is:

```
3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)
```

See below for the steps I took:

```
david@davids-imac:~/t $ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/david/t/.git/
david@davids-imac:~/t (master #) $ echo "hi" > t
david@davids-imac:~/t (master #%) $ git add t
david@davids-imac:~/t (master #) $ git commit -m 'added t'
[master (root-commit) 5f959d8] added t
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 t
```

One commit on master now.  Next, the new branch and a tag:

```
david@davids-imac:~/t (master) $ git checkout -b branch1
Switched to a new branch 'branch1'
david@davids-imac:~/t (branch1) $ echo "hello" > hello
david@davids-imac:~/t (branch1 %) $ git add .
david@davids-imac:~/t (branch1 +) $ git commit -m 'added hello'
[branch1 affb79a] added hello
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 hello
david@davids-imac:~/t (branch1) $ git tag v1.1.0.1
```

I now have a branch with a separate commit and that commit is tagged 'v1.1.0.1'.

Now to add one more commit to master (just to make sure the branches have diverged) and merge:

```
david@davids-imac:~/t (branch1) $ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
david@davids-imac:~/t (master) $ echo "yo" > yo
david@davids-imac:~/t (master %) $ git add .
david@davids-imac:~/t (master +) $ git commit -m 'added yo'
[master 93b09c4] added yo
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 yo
david@davids-imac:~/t (master) $ git log
commit 93b09c421e1939e3e85738fd5bd4d03b6429e729
Author: David Brown <david@davtar.org>
Date:   Wed Mar 14 20:24:13 2012 -0600

    added yo

commit 5f959d85a3059c189121c2b8687788c4384f9e6a
Author: David Brown <david@davtar.org>
Date:   Wed Mar 14 20:23:01 2012 -0600

    added t
david@davids-imac:~/t (master) $ git merge --no-ff -m "Released v1.1.0.1 to master." v1.1.0.1
Merge made by recursive.
 hello |    1 +
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 hello
```

The merge succeeded without opening any editor:

```
david@davids-imac:~/t (master) $ git log
commit ac2c62b86c3e631aeda27be601fcc92a9df61146
Merge: 93b09c4 affb79a
Author: David Brown <david@davtar.org>
Date:   Wed Mar 14 20:24:34 2012 -0600

    Released v1.1.0.1 to master.

commit 93b09c421e1939e3e85738fd5bd4d03b6429e729
Author: David Brown <david@davtar.org>
Date:   Wed Mar 14 20:24:13 2012 -0600

    added yo

commit affb79a9d72732b3250b7dca9cc8085b6f36faff
Author: David Brown <david@davtar.org>
Date:   Wed Mar 14 20:23:30 2012 -0600

    added hello

commit 5f959d85a3059c189121c2b8687788c4384f9e6a
Author: David Brown <david@davtar.org>
Date:   Wed Mar 14 20:23:01 2012 -0600

    added t
```

Comment: How strange. The steps you produced above are pretty much the same as mine. Yet on my Windows environment, the editor refuses to be bypassed even when a merge message is present. Strange. Thanks for investigating.

Comment: Ahh, yes, bash on windows can be a finicky thing. Have you tried adding quotes, single or double, around the tag name?